# Efficiently generating a topology from an STL file

Tags: c++, graphics

I have an STL file for a printable 3D shape.  An STL file is basically a bag full of facets (triangles with a normal) in 3 space that represent a 3D object.  Each facet is represented by 3 vertices and a normal.

Using a hash table I have match all the vertices that are equivalent and used that information to extract a topological model so I can ask for a relation ship such as getNearbyFacets() and countNearbyFacets().  This information is very important latter when contouring slices of the model.

Here is how I matched the verticies:

```
//used to compare pointers to the vertex objects
struct lex_compare {
    bool operator() (CAMu3DPoint const* lhs, CAMu3DPoint const* rhs) const{
        return *lhs == *rhs;
    }
};

//hash function for the verticies
struct lex_hash{
    std::size_t operator()(CAMu3DPoint const* vert) const{
        return
            (std::hash<float>()(vert->x)) ^
            (std::hash<float>()(vert->y)) ^
            (std::hash<float>()(vert->z));
    }
};
```

As I construct the facet list I shove all the vertices into an unordered_set then copy this set into a vector.  References to the vertices are stored in the facet object which allows for me to search based on neighboring facets.

This code is running slower than I would like it too.  My question is how can I create a topological relationship between my facets faster than this?

Comment: It is running slower doing what?

Comment: why hash ? you can compare the floats as integers instead that should be faster. But the slowest thing here is the list manipulation which I do not see anywhere in the code. sorting by (any) axises may help a lot

Comment: There is no list manipulation.  Just a list of facets in an unspecified order.  I want to find the relationship between facets that share the same verities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at data structures that are optimized for 3D nearest-neighbor searches. Here are the most popular ones:

- [Binary Space Partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) (BSP) and [k-d Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)
- [Locality-sensitive Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) (LSH)
- [r-Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree)

Comment: I ended up using boost::geometry::index::rtree

Comment: Great! Thanks for letting us know.